# Bluetooth discovery on Android - is there a way to know if there is a bluetooth device nearby?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I would like to show some kind of alert/notification if there is a bluetooth device nearby. At the moment my solution is to do the discovery every minute, but is there a more sophisticated way? (Like a BroadcastReceiver)

Comment: Have you found any solution to this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't.. You will have to perform discovery in your app or manually to discover devices

Answer (score 3):

the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Dennis. Unless you perform device discovery from your app, you won't be able to know the devices near to you.